# Mount: unknown filesystem type 'swap'

Tags: linux, debian, mount, swap, debian-jessie

I'm running vanilla Debian Jessie and I need to enable swap file. It works fine when I use `swapon /var/swap.img` but I'm unable to make it mount with fstab at boot time.

The following entry in fstab:

```
/var/swap.img none swap sw 0 0
```

Gives this error:

> Error mounting none: mount: unknown filesystem type 'swap'

What is the proper way to mount swap file on Debian with fstab?

**[Update]**

Adding all entries from fstab:

```
root@test:~# grep -v "#" /etc/fstab 
UUID=lorem-ipsum / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0 udf,iso9660 user,noauto 0 0
/var/swap.img none swap sw 0 0
```

Output from `df`:

```
root@test:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        20G  2.9G   16G  16% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M  8.4M   91M   9% /run
tmpfs           248M     0  248M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           248M     0  248M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Also output from `ls`:

```
root@test:~# ls -lh /var/swap.img 
-rw------- 1 root root 1000M Dec 16 17:55 /var/swap.img
```

I've also checked man and it's not listing swap as supported filesystem type. I'm confused (is this normal?):

> adfs, affs, autofs, btrfs, cifs, coda, coherent, cramfs, debugfs,  devpts, efs,  ext,  ext2,  ext3,  ext4, hfs, hfsplus, hpfs, iso9660, jfs, minix, msdos, ncpfs, nfs, nfs4, ntfs, proc, qnx4, ramfs, reiserfs, romfs, squashfs, smbfs, sysv, tmpfs, ubifs, udf, ufs, umsdos, usbfs, vfat, xenix,  xfs, xiafs.

Comment: That looks like a valid line.  My functioning jessie system has this. `/swapfile1   none    swap    sw    0   0`  Can you show us the full fstab?  Is `/var` on a separate filesystem?  Is your swap listed last?

Comment: @Zoredache I've updated my question with relevant information. As you can see the `/var` is on root filesystem.

Comment: `swap.img` is a silly name for a swapfile, since it's not a disk image.  Instead, consider `swap.swp` or `swap.dat` or `swapfile`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't mount the swap partition or swapfile with `mount`, you use the `swapon` command.  (The swap partition or file isn't really a filesystem that can be mounted and hold files, it's an area of the disk the kernel uses directly).

`swapon -a` will enable all swaps from `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Thanks. Having swap in `fstab` is what caused my confusion. I just wanted to test if the `fstab` entry for swap is correct, so obvious choice for me was to use `mount`. Apparently I was wrong.